# What is this count[str.charAt(i)]++;

Tags: java, arrays, string

I was trying to understand a java program to Count the Occurrences of Each Character. I saw a solution in a portal with a program which I have provided below,

```
// Java program for the above approach
class NoOfOccurrenceOfCharacters {
    static final int MAX_CHAR = 256;

    static void getOccurringChar(String str)
    {
        
        // Create an array of size 256 
        // i.e. ASCII_SIZE
        int count[] = new int[MAX_CHAR];

        int len = str.length();

        // Initialize count array index
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            count[str.charAt(i)]++;

        // Create an array of given String size
        char ch[] = new char[str.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            ch[i] = str.charAt(i);
            int find = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {

                // If any matches found
                if (str.charAt(i) == ch[j])
                    find++;
            }

            if (find == 1)
                System.out.println(
                    "Number of Occurrence of "
                    + str.charAt(i)
                    + " is:" + count[str.charAt(i)]);
        }
    }

    // Driver Code
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        String str = "geeksforgeeks";

        getOccurringChar(str);
    }
}
```

In the above code , Can some someone explain what does the line **count[str.charAt(i)]++;** means. Why that line is used and what is stored in that array. It would be really helpful if someone explains the code

Comment: `count` is just an array with 256 positions. A `char` is also equivalent to the [ASCII table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) number of that character. So when filling the array they are using the character index (say for instance for "A" is 65) so `count[str.charAt(i)]);` is equivalent to `count[65]` if `str.charAt(i)` returns an A);

Comment: This is a formula for counting character occurrances in a string.

Comment: Give it a try with the string `"geeks"`

Comment: That line means the author thinks it’s still 1990 and one character is equivalent to one byte.

Comment: tbf *one `char`* but that's not *much* better ;)

Comment: @g00se: Nope, one *byte* as far as I can see, given `static final int MAX_CHAR = 256`. No need to go out of the BMP to cause problems - just beyond ISO-8859-1.

Comment: @VGR this 1990 mindset perfectly fits the use of the legacy array syntax. My highlight, however, is how the optimized table approach is destroyed by a quadratic time complexity in the follow-up printing code…

Comment: @JonSkeet *Nope, one byte as far as I can see, given ...* Yes, you're right. Was forgetting that

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible equivalent to your code showing a way of dealing with e.g. the string "geeks". Modern Unicode characters often break the bounds of `char` so now need to be handled with `int`:

```
    static void getOccurringChar(String str) {
        Map<Integer, Long> counts = str.codePoints().boxed()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(c -> c, Collectors.counting()));
        counts.entrySet().stream().sorted(Map.Entry.<Integer, Long>comparingByKey())
                .forEach(e -> System.out.printf("%s = %d%n", new String(new int[] { e.getKey() }, 0, 1), e.getValue()));
    }
```

I'm really not sure why there doesn't exist a ctor for `String` that allows construction from a single `int` codepoint. Running with the above string:

```
goose@t410:/tmp$ java NoOfOccurrenceOfCharacters "geeks" 
e = 2
g = 1
k = 1
s = 1
 = 2
```

Apologies for the less than clear formatting. I'd probably need to tune my command line Eclipse formatter. If anyone knows the setting to format the chained calls one under the next, I'd be interested to know.

Comment: And now try with `"‍️‍"`. The takeaway is, even codepoints are not sufficient to handle *characters*. You can fix it by using `Pattern.compile("\\X").matcher(str).results() .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(MatchResult::group, Collectors.counting())) .entrySet().stream().sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey()) .forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.getKey() + " = " + e.getValue()));` but it’s ok to implement an operation with limitations, even only handling ASCII is ok, as long as the limitations are understood and documented.

Comment: Interesting ...

Comment: You can convert a single codepoint to a `String` using [`Character.toString(e.getKey())`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#toString(int)). But since you’re using `printf` anyway, you can also use `System.out.printf("%c = %d%n", e.getKey(), e.getValue())`

Comment: Doh! Yes you're right. Even so, strange that the ctor doesn't exist?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a step-by-step explanation:

for (int i = 0; i < len; i++): This is a standard for loop that starts with i initialized to 0 and continues as long as i is less than the length of the string str. The loop increments i in each iteration.

str.charAt(i): This expression retrieves the character at the current index i from the string str. The charAt(i) method is used to access the character at a specific index in a string.

count[str.charAt(i)]++: This line increments the count of the character found at index i in the string str. It uses the ASCII value of the character as the index in the count array. This means that each element in the count array corresponds to the count of a specific ASCII character.

str.charAt(i) gives the character at index i.
str.charAt(i) is cast to an int, which gives the ASCII value of that character.
count[str.charAt(i)]++ increments the count of that character in the count array.